# QGIS: Export 3D map in pdf not working

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, 3d, pdf

I am trying to export and save a 3D map as a pdf in QGIS 3.10 (using the composer).

I am using the native 3D viewer and I am trying to understand how I can export and save it as a pdf.

I set my 3D map in the main interface then I created the print layout (composer).

[image]
I added the "new 3D map" but the map was not displayed in the composer (white map).

Anyone can help me please?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the QGIS bug reporting page and see if this might be related to any known bugs (sometimes the bug reports also have advice about a workaround) https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Answer (score 1):

I should work the same way as exporting 2D map.

You have to set your 3D map in the main interface then create the print layout (composer) the same you way you will for 2D but you have to choose "Adds a new 3D map" and not "Adds a new map" (these are two different button or two defferent entry in the Add Item menu)

If you still can't make it work please edit your question with what you have tryed and what didn't wok

Answer (score 0):

[image: 3D Map View in Print Composer]
Ensure that after you have added a 3D Map Element to your layout, that you copy the 3D Map Scene Settings, and then set the Camera Pose from that same 3D View.

Both buttons you need to press are located in the 3D Map Item Properties in the Print Composer.

The above 3D Map element was empty for me until I did both steps in order as I've outlined above.

Comment: yes, I am doing the same steps as you suggested but still I can not visualize nothing

Comment: Are you keeping track of CPU usage? Is it busy trying to render the scene in the background?

Comment: yes, it is not too busy to rendering the background and the CPU usage is normal. Thank you in advance